# Accessing Views / View Controllers externally?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I have a custom view of `CustomViewA`, which contains and delegates to another view, `CustomViewB`.
In the end, the result of `CustomViewB` should be received on the containing View Controller, `MyViewController`.

I recently came across this handy way of accessing one views parent view controller, like so:

```
extension UIResponder {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        return next as? UIViewController ?? next?.parentViewController
    }
}
```

So it may look like weird practice, but are there any negative effects to writing something like:

```
// CustomViewA.swift
func protocolActionFromCustomViewB(objectToPass: CustomObject) {
    if let parent = self.parentViewController as? MyViewController {
        parent.performAction(with: objectToPass)
    }
}
```

Over creating another specific protocol or sending a notification?

On the same note, is there any negative effect to accessing values or calling functions from a view's superview? like so:

```
if let superview = superview as? MyCustomView {
    let object = superview.someObject
    superview.someFunction()
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are certainly downsides. The moment you nest your child view in something else (e.g. a scroll view), this will break.

Comment: `NotificationCenter` might be one approach, using another delegate might be another, I've taken to assigning callback closures/functions directly (which is a simple form of delegation)

Comment: I would advise against Notification Center. It really obscures connections between code. I think it's much  better to directly register `CustomViewB` as a delegate of `CustomViewA` (after making some `CustomVewADelegate` protocol, and extending `CustomViewB` to conform to it). It's clear, direct, performant and easily debuggable.

Comment: @Alexander The situation is that `CustomViewB` is alreay delegated by `CustomViewA`, where `CustomViewA` is the direct subview of the view controller and `CustomViewB` is a subview of `CustomViewA` and I need to get the object on `CustomViewB` to the View Controller. So I'm just trying to look out for other options other than stacking up multiple delegates, which gets cumbersome.

Comment: @Eilon Could you elaborate on by exactly what you mean by "In the end, the result of CustomViewB should be received on the containing View Controller, MyViewController." Are you talking about the result of the delegate method call on `CustomViewB`, and that you want `MyViewController` to use that result?